# Why does the material design dialog body have no height on an iPad

Tags: ios, angularjs, ipad, material-design

I have a web application using `angularjs` and `material-design`.

I use `md-dialog` for adding and editing certain records from the database. This is responsive and works as expected on my desktop for all browsers except `IE` (no great surprise). This is how it is supposed to look.

[image]

However, if I run the application in `safari` on a Mac, or any browser on `iOS` (including chrome), the dialog appears to be missing the contents (has no height).

[image]

While `IE` doesn't have exactly the same issue, it does appear to be similar. So, I believe it is an issue with how iOS renders the `flex` attributes. However, I am not sure and don't know how to confirm on my iPad.

My search so far has not provided any working solutions to this issue, but I have seen others ask the same question (though not through stack).

What causes this issue?
How do I fix it for an iPad?

**UPDATE**

This is how the dialog is rendered in the html:

```
<md-dialog-content class="flex" id="dialogContent_140" flex>
    <form name="workerDialog" class="md-dialog-content ng-pristine ng-invalid-required ng-valid-mindate ng-valid-maxdate nd-valid-filtered ng-valid-valid ng-valid-minlength ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid-pattern ng-valid-unique" style>
        ...
    </form>
</md-dialog-content>
```

If I modify the element and remove `flex` like this:

```
<md-dialog-content class="flex" id="dialogContent_140">
```

The body content appears as expected (at least on the MAC).

I can also modify the css in `angular-material.min.css` and remove `-webkit-flex`, `-ms-flex`, `flex` and achieve the same results.

```
[flex]{
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I can't completely kill `flex` for the rest of the application, but I have to allow this to work on an iPad.

Comment: could you provide the example code, it will help to investigate easily? I also had some issue with z-index and position css on Ipad before.

Comment: I would be happy to, but I am not sure what to provide. There is lots of code and this isn't a special implementation of material design dialog. What can I provide that would make it easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more information, with some special browser (e.g. IE, IOS browser...) we should consider to add the value for `flex`, like `flex="auto"` or `flex="100"`, it will help `anuglar-material` would fine on these browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the cause of my issues. Thanks to @Tran Khanh Nguyen for moving me in the right direction.

When the dialog was defined, someone added `<md-dialog-content flex>`. I removed `flex` and it fixed the issue on all devices.

Comment: Glad to hear it has resolved your problem! For more information, with some special browser (e.g. IE, IOS browser...) we should consider to add the value for `flex`, like `flex="auto"` or `flex="100"`, it will help `anuglar-material` would fine on these browsers.

Comment: add this comment as the answer and I will accept it :)

Comment: in my case it was class `flex-scrollable`